# Spinner onItemSelected to clear the EditText Text

Tags: android-edittext, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I have a spinner on one of my Activity that on initialization will load the data from database for `spinner.setSelection(0)`. When I change the spinner value, lets say `spinner.setSelection(1)`, I want to clear the text from `EdittText ed1` View prior to loading the data(if exist) or leave it blank/null/empty

Here is the snippet of my code.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity implements 
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
...
Spinner spinner;
EditText ed1;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
...    
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed1);
...
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.temp_layout01,R.id.temptxt01,xNames);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(getSpinnerIndex(spinner,mname));
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Method to clear the EditText data

```
private void clearAllFields() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clearing Fields");
            ed1.getText().clear(); //test that didn't clear the data
            ed1.setText(null); // test that didn't clear the data
    }
```

onItemSelected for spinner listener

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    clearAllFields();
    mname = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    mID = dbHelper.getCurrentData(mname);
    spinner.setSelection(getSpinnerIndex(spinner,mname));
    populateData();
}
```

The ed1 is within a TableRow

```
<TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tbHole18TR"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
           <EditText
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/ed1"
                android:background="@color/Green3"
                android:textAlignment="center" />
        </TableRow>
```

Is this something to do with focusChange etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

1. get current spinner data and EditText data
2. compare them if find not equal clear else do nothing